# install windows service in windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-services, installation, uac

i use the code for install Service in XP:

```
@"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Path  +@"\service.exe
```

But in Windows 7 this code is problem

Comment: I believe that you need to provide more information to get any answer!

Comment: oki then whats the problem ??

Comment: Are you using an account with the right privileges for installing services?

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 7 you have to run the command line as admin for this to work.

To do that, click the Start "orb", type "cmd" as usual but instead of pressing Enter, hold `CTRL`+`SHIFT` together then press Enter. Dialog will appear, confirm it and you'll get administrative access and the installation should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I use "installutil.exe -i myAppExe" command for installing. Cant you use this command?

Answer (score 0):

Only an elevated process (it is not enough to be logged into the machine as a member of the Administrators group) can install a service. If you're doing it from the command prompt, make it an elevated one (right clicking the shortcut and choosing Run As Administrator works, as well as @Shadow Wizard's instructions.) If you're doing it in code, the app will need to be elevated.